# Replace multiline text in a file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to replace multiple lines of text in a file.

Example:
I want to replace

```
Hello
World
```

With

```
Hi
Programmer
```

Can anyone help.

Comment: this might be of help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -p -0777 -e 's/Hello\nWorld/Hi\nProgrammer/g'
```

- `-0777` enables the slurp mode, i.e. it reads the whole file as a single block. You can also use `-00` which enables the paragraph mode: it reads the input in blocks separated by at least two newlines, so unless the text to replace contains two consecutive newlines, you can use this mode, too.
- `-p` for each block, it runs the code and prints the result

Answer (score 0):

Using this command you can accomplish your task.  `sed -i 's/Hello\nWorld/Hi\nProgrammer/g' your_file.txt`

Comment: This also replace "Hello Mars" by "Hi Mars".

Comment: Sed processes the input line by line. Multiline matching doesn't work in sed.